# filter with dplyr based on a condition that only applies to a subset of data

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to use dplyr's filter() function to filter only a subset of a dataframe?

This is a simple example:

```
> df <- structure(list(ColA = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y"), ColB = c(1, 
                                                                      2, 3, 1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("ColA", "ColB"), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

> df
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   ColA  ColB
  <chr> <dbl>
1     x     1
2     x     2
3     x     3
4     y     1
5     y     2
6     y     3
```

I would like to filter cases where column "ColB" is "1", but only in those cases where "ColA" is "y". This is the wanted result:

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   ColA  ColB
  <chr> <dbl>
1     x     1
2     x     2
3     x     3
4     y     1
```

With base R it is not difficult...

```
df[df$ColA == "x" | (df$ColA == "y" & df$ColB == 1),]
```

And it shouldn't be with dplyr... but I still cannot fully get this slightly not typical cases... where I have to work with subsets of data (I am still not clear whether this is possible or in which cases)
The data I am working with is much bigger than this and I am using dplyr's pipes. It will just be easier to read and faster if I manage to use dplyr.

Thanks!!

Comment: `df[df$ColA == "x" | (df$ColA == "y" & df$ColB == 1),]` when you have `NA`, it will bring trouble, for base R using `subset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easy peasy

```
df  %>% filter((ColA == "x") | (ColA == "y" & ColB == 1))
```

Comment: Definitely too easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is almost the same as the base R. What you need to do is put the condition in the argument of the `filter` function. I changed `==` to `%in%` but for your example dataset, they result in the same output because there are no `NA` in `ColA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(ColA %in% "x" | (ColA %in% "y" & ColB == 1))
```